# How to populate VB.NET multidimensional dropdownlist?

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, executereader

I am trying to initialize a dropdownlist in VB.NET but my dropdownlist is not populating any values.  I want the DataTextField to be different from DataValues in the dropdownlist.  Dropdownlist should display series of strings; DataValues should only be numbers.

How can I implement this?  Here is my code excerpt right now:

```
Dim ProductList As New ArrayList()
Dim ProdCodeSearch As String
Dim InstrumentSearch As String

pcSQL = " select distinct instrument_name AS [instrument_name], product_code AS [product_code] from FRUD.tblXref order by instrument_name "
Dim DBConn As SqlConnection
DBConn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AMDMetricsDevConnectionString"))
DBConn.Open()
Dim reader As SqlDataReader
Dim DBCommand As New SqlCommand(pcSQL, DBConn)       
reader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader()

While reader.Read()
End While

dProdCodeSearch.Items.Add(reader(0))
dProdCodeSearch.DataTextField = "instrument_name"
dProdCodeSearch.DataValueField = "product_code"
dProdCodeSearch.DataBind()
reader.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use something like this?

```
While reader.Read()
   Dim ListItem as new ListItem
   ListItem.Text = reader(0)
   ListItem.Value = reader(1)
   dProdCodeSearch.Items.Add(ListItem)
End While
```

it usually works for me..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code as follows, I assume you are using ASP.NET

```
Dim ProductList As New ArrayList()
Dim ProdCodeSearch As String
Dim InstrumentSearch As String

pcSQL = " select distinct instrument_name AS [instrument_name], product_code AS [product_code] from FRUD.tblXref order by instrument_name "
Dim DBConn As SqlConnection
DBConn = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AMDMetricsDevConnectionString"))
DBConn.Open()
Dim reader As SqlDataReader
Dim DBCommand As New SqlCommand(pcSQL, DBConn)       
reader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader()

While reader.Read()
    dProdCodeSearch.Items.Add(reader(0))
End While

dProdCodeSearch.DataTextField = "instrument_name"
dProdCodeSearch.DataValueField = "product_code"
reader.Close()
```

Comment: This was helpful. But I am trying to get the underlying value (data value). Your code above returns the DataTextField both in the dropdownlist control and in my dProdCodeSearch.SelectedValue line. Also, your code snippet adds items from reader(0), but what about reader(1)? That is what I am trying to get data from to populate my SQL query. Make sense?

Comment: There is only one reader, with two columns of data. You are adding each row of the reader to dProdCodeSearch's list of Items. When you run this, do you see the display value you are expecting? The dataValue field won't be visible.  Are you having issues getting the value after it is selected?

Comment: What you are prob. going to want to do then is first, read your data into a list of objects, then you can either 1) Add them to the items collection (as in the code snippet above) or 2) Set the DataSource property on the dropdown list and databind.